# How to draw square based on a random dimension and display the size

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to draw a square with random size but I don't know how to do this with Javascript. I would like to know how to display the random size in text box on html page

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
 <script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
  context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 7;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

this will draw a fill rectangular, but i want it as square , with random size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

HTML:

```
   <input type="text" id="size"></input>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var min = 10;
var max = 50;
var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

document.getElementById("size").value = size; //this will print random dimension in text input #size

context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, size, size);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
//context.lineWidth = 7;
//context.strokeStyle = 'black';
//context.stroke();                  --I've commented it out to make it more clear - you can uncomment it
```

to draw square with dimension from **min** to **max**. This one will be always started i (0,0) but you can also random start point.

The size will be displayed in the input

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/615eodon/

Comment: thank you , but if i want to make a function to return the size , how to give it to the `context.rect(0,0,size,size)` , and display the size in text field ?

Comment: you can display the text using `document.getElementById("size").value = size;` no matter if in this code or in some function. I'm pretty sure you cannon do something like *"check what is the size of drawn shape"* but you have to keep somewhere its size to actually render it so you have an access to it